# Are Firestore Collections Physically Isolated from Each Other?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, multi-tenant

I am considering storing multiple tenants in a single Firebase Firestore database. There will only be one collection per tenant and a few shared collections. Some will have more data than others. Some tenants may have a few million records while others may end up with a few billion. I want to confirm that the size of data in one collection will not impact the performance or storage of another collection in the same database.

I couldn't find much in the documentation about how the data is physically stored. Is all the data in Firestore stored in a single blob/file? If so, this could be a problem when there are hundreds of tenants with billions of records each. In an ideal world, each collection would be a physically separate file, and the server orchestration would separate the collections onto multiple servers so that a single server is not sharing the load between a very heavy tenant, and a very light tenant. This scenario would mean that a heavy tenant would slow down a light tenant.

My basic question is: *can a single Firestore database infinitely scale up in size assuming that no single collection is bigger than a few billion records?*

I know that there are two types of databases: native and datastore. Which of these seems more appropriate, and is the answer to my question different depending on which of these I select?

If the answer is that Firestore cannot scale infinitely in this way, *what is the alternative approach? Should I be using Bigtable instead? Cassandra? Or, is there another way to physically divide my Firestore database other than collections?*

Answer (score 1):

> Some tenants may have a few million records while others may end up with a few billion. I want to confirm that the size of data in one collection will not impact the performance or storage of another collection in the same database.

The performance in Firestore isn't related to the number of documents that exist in a collection. In terms of speed, it doesn't matter if you perform a query on:

- A top-level (root-level) collection.
- A sub-collection, which basically represents a collection that is nested under a document.
- A collection group, which actually means querying collections and sub-collections that exist across the entire database.

The speed will always be the same, as long as the query returns the same number of documents. This is happening because the query performance depends on the number of documents you request and **not** on the number of documents you search. So it doesn't really matter if you query a collection with 1 MILLION documents or even 1 BILLION documents, the time for getting the same results will be the same.

> I couldn't find much in the documentation about how the data is physically stored. Is all the data in Firestore stored in a single blob/file? If so, this could be a problem when there are hundreds of tenants with billions of records each.

In Cloud Firestore, the unit of storage is the document. Documents live in collections, which are simply containers for documents. Please note that Firestore is optimized for storing **large** collections of small documents. And when I say large, I mean extremely large. So when you perform a query against a collection of 1 MILLION documents, the speed depends on the number of results you return and it does **not** depend on the number of the documents in which you search, or on the number of documents that exist in other collections in which you aren't performing a search.

> Can a single Firestore database infinitely scale up in size assuming that no single collection is bigger than a few billion records?

While when using the Firebase Realtime Database you had to [scale using multiple databases](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/sharding), in Firestore this practice is not necessary. However, the are some techniques that are really good explained in the official docs:

- [Building scalable applications with Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/building-scalable-apps-with-cloud-firestore)

> If the answer is that Firestore cannot scale infinitely in this way, what is the alternative approach?

I can definitely massively scale.

Comment: Hey Christian. Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

See the Firestore [best practices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices) and [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

You may conceptualize Firestore as being one service being shared by **all** of Google's customers. Just as Google's attempts to ensure that one customer's (so-called "noisy neighbor") impact on the service does not affect others, you don't want to be a noisy neighbor to yourself.

You need to consider more than just performance.

- **Security**. E.g.see [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) as a mechanism that you may be able to use to help enforce segregation of your tenants' data. You will want to understand fully how to keep different customers' data separated securely. Your customers will want to understand what measures you're employing to ensure their data is keep separate too.
- **Multitenancy**. Google Cloud Platform has no intrinsic (platform-wide) multitenant capabilities and, often, a way to manifest tenancy has been to use different Google Projects for different customers. This is because Projects provide a well-defined security perimeter. You may want to investigate whether (some subset of your customers) would benefit from being one customer, one project.
- **Quota**. Another important consideration is quota. Every Cloud Platform method is constrained by some quota. You will want to be careful in ensuring that quota is distributed fairly across customers so that some customers don't consume all the quota denying other customers access to the service.